# How to copy and replace an element and its children in Python with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So, I have two HTML files and they both have divs in with an ID of htmlbody. I want to check if the htmlbody element in one file is the same as the htmlbody element in another file. If it isn't then I want to copy the htmlbody element and replace it in the file that is different. Please see my code below.

I have tried using the Modifying the Tree Docs here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append

```
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def getMainFile():
    #opens and pareses the main html file
    main_html = codecs.open("index.html", 'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(main_html, 'html.parser')
    #assignes the HTML content of the main file to a variable.
    html_content = soup.find(id="htmlbody")
    return html_content

#User Html file
  def getUserFile():
     user_html = codecs.open("userone.html", 'r')
     soup = BeautifulSoup(user_html, 'html.parser')
     soup.prettify()
     html_content = soup.find(id="htmlbody")
     return html_content


 #Checks files
 if getMainFile() == getUserFile():
    print("all good")
 else:
    new_content = getMainFile()
    user_html = codecs.open("userone.html", 'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(user_html, 'html.parser')

  with open("userone.html", "w") as file:
      file.write(str(soup.prettify()))
```

Comment: What are the errors/exceptions that you get?

Comment: markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: and also AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'